# Show all the create tables from a database?

Tags: mysql

I know that with a mysql_dump I can get the current tables and data inside of those tables into a sql file.

However, how can I get just the CREATE TABLE descriptions? I don't want to carry all the data, just be able to create the same tables in my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqldump -d -u someuser -p mydatabase > backup.sql
```

The -d option is the --no-data option

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data

Answer (score 0):

You want the -d switch (or --no-data) for mysqldump (not mysql_dump) - it means "no data".

Answer (score 0):

```
show create table `table_name`
```

will show the create structure.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html